# Is $f$ identically zero on $[0, 1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function on $[0,1]$ such that there is $K>0$ for which $|f(x)|\le K \int_0^x|f(t)|dt$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Does it follow that $f=0$ on $[0,1]$?

What I know is just $f(0)=0.$

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 $K$ is a fixed positive constant here.

Comment: Just something that comes to mind: since $f(0) = 0$ you can write: $|f(x)| \leq K \int |f(t) - f(0)| dt \leq K \epsilon x$ for all $x$, where the $\epsilon$ comes from continuity.

Comment: But then i think we require some $\delta$ too!.like $|t|<\delta$ ?@PiotrBenedysiuk

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168141/show-that-f-is-identically-zero-if-fx-leq-int-0xftdt?rq=1

Comment: @md2perpe Both those proof only work if $K \leq 1$.

Comment: @md2perpe I figured out by modifying the linked proof. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set
$$
F(x)=\int_0^x |\,f(t)|\,dt,\quad x\in[0,1],
$$
then $F$ is continuously differentiable and satisfies
$$
F'(x)\le Kf(x), \quad F(x)=0.
$$
Hence
$$
\big(\mathrm{e}^{-Kx}F(x)\big)'=\mathrm{e}^{-Kx}\big(F'(x)- Kf(x)\big)\le 0,
$$
and thus
$$
\mathrm{e}^{-Kx}F(x)\le \mathrm{e}^{-K\cdot 0}F(0)=0,
$$
for all $x\in[0,1]$, which implies that
$$
\int_0^x|\,f(t)|\,dt=F(x)=0, \quad\text{for all $x\in[0,1]$},
$$
and consequently, $\,f\equiv 0$.